# EventToCommand async?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, mvvm-light

I am writing a WPF program where I use EventToCommand to handle events in third party controls and wire them up to ICommands.  My view model methods are all async and the problem I am having that the events are not waiting for the handlers to complete.  Problem is  a bit long to illustrate in WPF but I summarized it in the little console app below.

My general question is is there an implementation of EventToCommand that will allow me to use async handlers?  Yes I did google it found nothing.  The mvvm-light documentation [here](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/NET45/index.html) says nothing about async.

I am open to any work around that get the job done.  Note in the code below I use the name "ButtonClick" which may lead you to ask why I don't just bind to the command.... that was a poor naming choice for the example sorry.  In my WPF app I am handling events for which there is no command.

```
class Program
{
    public event EventHandler ButtonClickEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program");
        var p = new Program();
    }

    public Program()
    { 
        ButtonClickEvent += ButtonClickEventHandler;
        Console.WriteLine("Start fire event");
        ButtonClickEvent(this, new EventArgs()); // In WPF app this event is handled by EventToCommand, which executes an ICommand
        Console.WriteLine("End fire event");
        Console.Write("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Output
        // Start fire event
        // Start GetStringAsync
        // End fire event            <-- not waiting
        // End GetStringAsync
    }

    // In WPF app this method is wired up to a DelegateCommand
    public async void ButtonClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DownloadStuffAsync();
    }

    public async Task DownloadStuffAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start GetStringAsync");
        string page = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("http://www.ibm.com");
        Console.WriteLine("End GetStringAsync");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventHandlers doesn't support asynchronous methods. You need some `Task` returning method as a workaround and await the `Task` where you invoke the event.

You can use Deferral as explained [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) in Stephen Cleary's article on the subject. There are other solutions like overriding the `SynchronizationContext` but using something like shown in the above article is better.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem I am having that the events are not waiting for the handlers to complete.
>
> My general question is is there an implementation of EventToCommand that will allow me to use async handlers?

Well, look at the problem from the perspective of the third-party control. It's raising an event that looks something like this:

```
void ControlEvent(object sender, ControlEventArgs args);
```

When that delegate returns, it's done. The event handler signature returns `void`, and all the arguments are data being passed *from* the control *to* the event handler. There's no "return communication". There's no way for the delegate to tell the third-party control "I'm not actually totally done yet; I'm just returning to free up the thread because I'm asynchronous; I have more code to execute later and then I'll *really* be done."

So, in short, what you want to do will probably require non-trivial changes to the third-party control. There are [various hacks to try to force the asynchronous code to complete synchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) (as I describe in a recent MSDN article), but none of them work very well. A better solution as Sriram said is to change the third-party control to use Deferrals; I describe [one possible implementation of Deferrals](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) on my blog. However, this will be a non-trivial change for the third-party control, one which they may be unwilling to make.

Comment: Stephen, in your article you say "Other frameworks such as  (WPF) permit asynchronous event handlers. So, for example, a button click event might be async void."  Do you think a bit of a qualifier might be fitting there, perhaps something like "...but they don't work half the time and they introduce bugs" might be fitting?   I really appreciate all the great posts you have written but I feel sometimes like we are never getting the real story on async.  So many times I read an answer like "its easy!  Go async all the way down!"  But where the rubber meets the road there is grief.

Comment: @Sam: In this case, it's the third-party control that is causing all the problems, not WPF. WPF works well with `async`/`await`; but if you have a library that doesn't support `async`, then (of course) that library gets confused if you use `async`.

Comment: Stephen, please read your own words "There's no "return communication". There's no way for the delegate to tell the third-party control...".  Its not the fault of the third party control!  You would do much more to champion your cause by being explicit, clear, and complete when you discuss issues like this.  No one is casting blame - just tell us the whole truth so we know what to expect.

Comment: @Sam: Sorry for not being clear. The problem lies entirely with the third-party control. The control is using an event as an implementation callback, not a mere notification. It is using an implementation of the Observer pattern to implement a Strategy pattern. And this happens to work for .NET events - *as long as the Strategy is synchronous*. As soon as an asynchronous Strategy implementation comes along, the third-party control breaks *because it is treating its Strategies as Observers*.

Comment: "And this happens to work for .NET events - as long as the Strategy is synchronous."  So the machine always works...as long as its not turned on?   Here is  a .net control that implements same pattern as my third party control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending(v=vs.110).aspx.  Here we expect e.Cancel to be set for the control to work properly. This is common throughout the framework, even event bubbling/tunneling (IsHandled). This is a core concept. Are Microsoft's own controls non-compliant?

Comment: BTW Stephen I am not arguing about how things should be or what is right or wrong or which pattern is what.  i am saying be careful not to imply event handlers just work when there are material obstacles to overcome when implementing them.

Comment: @Sam: Yes, any event that assumes the handler has completed when it returns is not async-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution on the link giving by Sriram in my comment in WPF and it does work.

My ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        DoSomethingCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSomething);
    }

    private async void DoSomething()
    {
        await DownloadStuffAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("Button Call Completed");
    }
    public async Task DownloadStuffAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start GetStringAsync");
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread sleeping");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        string page = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("http://www.ibm.com").ConfigureAwait(false);
        Debug.WriteLine("End GetStringAsync");
    }
}
```

My View

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Do Something" Margin="0,2,2,2" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and the Output on the debug window

[image]

Comment: When executed in UI application, [your code will deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: It won't deadlock but it will freeze. What is also quite odd is that in one way the user wants the download process to complete before the application gets usable.

Comment: Nope, it will deadlock. You can try it out. There are lots of posts which talk about this. Refer the article in my above comment for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the article. Indeed it was useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sam event is nothing but a trigger which notifies that something has happened like Button click or mouse move. If you want to start doing something on that do that. But handle your async needs after that. Can you please explain the exact scenario what you need. so that I can help more?

Thanks
Ankit